# Citation after etc word

Tags: citations, keywords

I have a question regarding proper usages of a citation number after the "*etc*" word.

So the sentence goes like this:

> This is a random sentence about words and etc. Here is another
> sentence. Now If I would like to cite, should the number in brackets
> be before the dot, or after?

**Option 1:**

> This is a random sentence about words and etc **[1]**. Here is another sentence.

**Option 2:**

> This is a random sentence about words and etc. **[1]** Here is another sentence.

I have no idea which one is correct. I would appreciate all help!

Comment: Aside from the comments from @astronat and apnorton about avoiding etc in a context where you would be citing something, the *et* in *et cetera* translates to **and**.   So you would never ever say "and etc." because it's like saying "and and"...

Comment: If the typesetting is screaming this badly, it's often a good idea to take it as a sign that there are better phrasings out there and that the paragraph could use some reshaping.

Comment: @Fred Douglis this is a very good point. Compare to the similar **&c.**

Comment: Latin abbreviations (etc., i.e., e.g.) are bad style in general. . Writing "random sentence about words and so on [1]." is already strictly better. All other revisions suggested also apply.

Comment: @Blaisorblade [citation needed]. For example, the Chicago Manual of Style discourages "etc." specifically but doesn't seem to discourage other Latin abbreviations.

Comment: Sorry I retract: I was thinking i.e. and e.g. specifically, and they're only agreed to be often confused and misused. I've been taught to avoid them because they're confusing: abbreviating a foreign language doubles the understanding effort. But I agree multiple style choices are acceptable.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The full stop indicates that etc. is a contraction of *et cetera*. This means that the citation should come after the dot:

> etc. [1]

If this is the end of the sentence, put a second full stop after the citation:

> etc. [1].

As an aside, my old English teacher told me that using etc. is bad form; if you have other things to list, be explicit and list them. If not, don't waste space with the pointless filler. (However, I myself have often broken this rule.)

Comment: +1 especially for the last paragraph.  If you're using "etc." in academic writing, you need to be more specific.

Comment: I agree with the 'bad form' point.  To me, if an author uses 'etc', it simply says 'i don't know', or 'I'm too lazy to list the items for you'.

Comment: Yes, except a few journals have the reference after the full stop rather than before, in which case you shouldn't have two (if *etc.* ends a sentence you would only have one).  This is perhaps more common with a superscript citation style.

Comment: Using "etc" at the end of a list makes explicit that the list is not inclusive. This might be because a few elements are omitted, in which case one can argue that they should be added. However, the full list may be simply too large for the paper - laziness is not the only reason to shorten it. The list might not even be finite - "The prime numbers, 2,3,5, etc. have the property ...". If you omit the "etc", you would be talking about just those 3 prime numbers. (Of course I'm using prime numbers as an meta-example here, no real paper would need to have examples of prime numbers)

Comment: @MSalters Though in most publications (academic writing in general?) it is more common to see something like "We have studied cats including, but not restricted to, feral kittens, siam cats and calico cats." instead of "We have studied feral kittens, siam cats, calico cats etc." This involves mentioning the "category" you are using, which is not obvious with the etc (would dogs be included because this is about pets or is it just cats that have been studied?)

Comment: @skymningen: Critical difference there: the list of cats you studied is a finite list. There I would agree with the above-mentioned opinion of listing them all. It would be another matter if you stated "Previous research on feline diets covered feral kittens [...], Siam cats [...], and calico cats [...]." (quoting other sources than yourself).

Comment: It wasn't meant to be a finite list. Thus "including but not restricted to". There are many breeds/types of cats that could have been studied. Persian cats, neutered male cats, cats with diabetes, ...they are all cats, but there isn't necessarily a finite amount of subgroups of cats. Maybe it was a bad example. Let's say "We plan on studying cats, including but not restricted to (list)." Then the final decision of the selected cats is not made yet, there are many options but they definitely will be cats.